# Clipboard manager for 12.04 Unity

Tags: unity, clipboard-manager

What clipboard manager can be used for Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Unity? I tried [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/) and [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper) - both not working. [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/) remains invisible, [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper) crashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clipboard manager with "history paste" support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253963/clipboard-manager-with-history-paste-support)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [ClipIt](http://clipit.rspwn.com/). It works on both Gnome3 and Unity. Install it with

```
sudo apt install clipit
```

Comment: Thanks, clipit works in my Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome, but remains invisible in Unity. Looks like the same problem as with other clipboard managers.

Comment: Are you sure its running? It works in my gnome and unity. On 12.10.. but it doesn't start automatically, you have to start it.

Comment: I also found this discussion useful: http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/how-to-get-a-clipboard-manager-onto-the-top-panel-in-unity-in-12-04-td4959684.html

Answer (score 13):

Try [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon), which comes with a Unity integration such as an application indicator and a Unity Lens.

Comment: After installing about 20 different Diodon prerequisites, I give up - looks like this project is not ready yet :(

Comment: Were you installing it from the ppa or from source?

Comment: I installed it from the ppa, no problem and works perfectly :)

Comment: That's a really nice clipboard manager. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally a worthy replacement of the old Glipper I've used for years!

Comment: The diodon ppa is supported up to 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Parcellite just released a version with appindicator. You can also white list it. [Details in 1.1.4 release notes](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/), and [PPA for appindicator](https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite-appindicator).

Answer (score 0):

[Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/) is another one you can give a try.